# Interrupting the main thread with no impact on existing code

Tags: interrupted-exception

How can interrupt the main thread, without any impact on existing code execution?

Because as you know the code Thread.sleep(); has impact on the before codes.

What I do need specifically is a code that force the program to impulse for 1sec and then run the rest of it. But do not effect on the hole program (I mean the codes that wrote before that code)

Comment: - What are „before codes“? If you sleep a thread, this thread is blocked for some time, but the other threads continue, as far as possible. Maybe you can describe you problem more precisely? Then you would get probably better answers.

Comment: we dont have any other thread in program.

Comment: I have some lights in UI. and i want take on these lights but within 50 milliseconds of each other. and the next codes execute next of them.

Comment: Based on your clarification, you might want to reword the question as: _"How to make the program execute some code once every second"_. You're not really looking into interrupting the thread or blocking it, but to execute a given task ("UI lights") once every so often. A timer that places a message in your event queue is one way of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution for my question :
we can use one array of threads and one array of handlers and postDelayed method for this.

for example this code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < executeCount; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    arrayThread.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            arrayhandler.get(j).postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doSomeThings();

                    if(j == executeCount -1){
                        doNextCodes();  
                    }
                }
            }
            , (j * WaitingTime));
        }
     }));
 arrayThread.get(j).start();
 }
```

this code execute "doSomeThings();" per "WaitingTime" seconds for "executeCount" times. and in final when "j == executeCount -1" program execute "doNextCodes();" .